# Charting journey frequency in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I have a list of 10 start destination and 25 Points of Interest(POI) like;

```
Start            POI
Town A           Aquarium
Town B           Library
Town C           Museum
Town D           Fair
Town E           Race Track
                 Auto Track
                 Planetarium
```

Each journey is from a Start to a POI, I want to visually show the journey and the frequency, so it could be a line from Town A to Library, the line gets thicker the higher the journey frequency. How can I create a chart that could represent this, is it possible.

Comment: When you say "from a Start to a POI" do you mean that you want each listed on a side of a chart and draw lines between them?

Comment: possibly do able in power BI, however your data would need to be put together in a model, maybe written in SQL, something like `Select Start, POI, Count, from Source` the count would then represent line thickness or colour etc.

Comment: @EdB Yes that sounds right, difference colours for each journey and also  the thickness of the lines to represent the frequency of the journey.